# Probability density function in Rayleigh distribution

Tags: probability, density-function

It says that

$$
f(x;\theta) = (x/\theta)e^{-x^2/(2\theta^2)},  x>0
$$

is the Rayleigh distribution.

And asks to verify that $f(x;\theta)$ is a legitimate pdf.

Can you explain how to verify legitimate pdf and what $f(x;\theta)$ means?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the properties that a distribution satisfies?

In particular, does the density integrate to $1$ over $(0,\infty)$? Verify that it does.

Also the notation $f(x;\theta)$ is represents the density, where $x$ is the variable, and $\theta>0$ is a fixed parameter.

Comment: Ah! thank you. Can I ask you another quick question? What is the difference between at most and less than? Aren't P(X<100) and P(X<=100) the same when I do integral?

Comment: @TYN If a thing $Y$ is at most $a$, then $Y\leq a$. If a thing $Y$ is less than $b$, then $Y< b$. When dealing with continuous random variables, $P(X<100)$ and $P(X\leq 100)$ are the same thing.

Comment: @TYN No problem! Good, luck.